What is the source for Cixi dreaming on the train?
There is a persistent narrative that Cixi (Empress Dowager of the Qing Dynasty) dreamt badly on her first train voyage and therefore banished trains to a place far from Beijing. This was made a film in 1991 or 1990 and is narrated as fact on some website.
As the film contains inaccuracies (showing a Manchu considering crows inauspicious, f. e.), I wonder whether there is any earlier source for this evil dream and banishment of trains (or if the makers of that film were indeed the first to make it up).

There is one mention of her taking a train to Beijing in her WP bio you linked. If I'm mathing right, she would have been 66 at the time. That seems unrealistically old to have been her first ever train ride, and would leave only 6 years of her life for trains to have been banned. I'm guessing the movie depicted that happening much earlier?

Any evidence that this story is anything other than purely fictional?

The Wikipedia article on rail transport in China says "To secure the support of the Empress Dowager Cixi for railway construction, Li Hongzhang imported a small train set from Germany and built a 2 kilometres (1.2 mi) narrow gauge railway from her residence in Zhongnanhai to her dining hall in Beihai in 1888. The Empress, concerned that the locomotive's noise would disturb the geomancy or fengshui of the imperial city, required the train be pulled by eunuchs instead of steam engine."

@SteveBird Yes that is certainly not the train track depicted. The journey depicted takes Cixi to Qinhuangdao and other far away places. But I am mostly interested with the reality or fictionality of the dream and concomitant decision.

@BrianZ the Dream and banning are depicted as fact on the website I linked, but I am highly doubtful

@T.E.D. The Cixi in the movie looks pretty old, but I cannot gauge her age more accurately. I would interpret the dream as suggesting it was after the Boxer rebellion (making her 66 or older, as you said).

@Ludi I am doubtful too, but how to prove a dream never occurred? What evidence is the question asking for?

@BrianZ evidence of this tale being older than 1990 (so that I can formulate better hypotheses  on why it was made up or change my mind and believe it may be partly true)!

@Ludi If such evidence existed I don't think it would be hard to find. It probably doesn't exist.
